# How to get distribution list (not group) with its members inside the Outlook using the OfficeJS or Graph API?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin

I'm trying to get the distribution list of people/members inside the Outlook add-in.

That distribution/contact list is not the "group" as it was created inside the "*Outlook People*" section using the option to create "***New contact list***" as described on the image below:

[image: contact-list]

I can see that list is created and listed at "*Your contact lists*" like on the following image:

[image: your-contact-lists]

And it can be added as the recipient in the mail as can be seen on the next image:

[image: recipient-contact-list]

But I couldn't find a proper API for getting that data neither using the OfficeJS nor the Graph API. I saw some suggestions to fetch the "groups" using the Graph API endpoint:  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups`, but once again, this is only a (distribution) list of contacts, not a group.

I'd appreciate it if someone from the MSFT team has a suggestion on how to solve this by providing a solution for getting 3 things:

1. Get the list of distribution/contact lists
2. Get the members of a specific contact list
3. Check if the recipient has a mail or is just a contact list without a mail

Thanks

Comment: Did you go through the API documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.recipients?view=outlook-js-preview
You can use addAsync method to add the recipients.

Comment: @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT this answer makes me feel that you really don't know your product! the question is on now get the recipients list of the group, not get the type of the recipients, however, I don't see in the whole question how to add a recipient list!

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I did go through the documentation, but it seems that you didn't understand my question as I'm mainly asking how to get the list of all my distribution lists along with their members. If you could please read it again and give a valid answer or ask if something is not very clear. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Could you please have a look at the Ews APIs that helps retrieve Contact Details including DLs?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/jj220498(v=exchg.80)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/expanddl-operation
Ews request can be initiated via Add-in using makeEwsRequestAsync API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#makeEwsRequestAsync_data__callback__userContext_

Comment: Is there any clear answer for this? how can get the contact list

Answer (score 0):

I up your question as I'm also looking for the answer to your question, unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to increase the up value. Not sure if you have come to a solution?

I understand that you mentioned that the 'groups' here does not imply 'Memberships' in Outlook. Just wondering if you have [tested the API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users&version=v1.0) and come to this conclusion? I tried this Graph Explorer, however I have permission issues so I could not verify.

**Get the members of a specific contact list** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

**Get the list of distribution/contact lists** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If 'distribution list' is 'contacts' under contacts folder [as suggested by MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/jj220498(v=exchg.80)), will the following API work? 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Thanks!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30056680)